# R Hmisc html function

Tags: html, r, hmisc

In a Quarto document being prepared for html output, I want to use the Hmisc::describe() function with the html() function, thus:

`html(describe(diffs$gama_diff))`

I get the following error: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument is not a character vector`

`gama_gt` is a numeric vector, but I think the error refers to the output of the describe() function.

I am in a Windows 11 environment in RStudio with R4.2.0. The YAML uses `format: html:` and a number of sub-arguments.

I'm sure the error is mine, but I'm not sure what it is that I've done.

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. What is `class(describe(diffs$gama_diff))` ?

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct version: there's also `testthat::describe` and `terra::describe`, both expect strings. If you change your `html(describe(...))` to `html(Hmisc::describe(...))`, does the problem resolve?

Comment: FYI, your code references `diffs$gama_diff` but you say that `gama_gt` is a numeric vector. I don't know if you're referring to the column of a frame or a standalone, but the code and your statement are not the same.

Comment: Finally, it would help to make this question reproducible, please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you r2evans. Your comments put me in the right direction. Here is a reproducible version of the error using iris: 

`library(Hmisc)`

`library(gt)`

`describe(iris$Sepal.Length)`

`html(describe(iris$Sepal.Length))`

The conflict was with the `gt` package, which also has an `html()` function. Changing the last line of the example to `Hmisc::html(describe(iris$Sepal.Length))` fixes the problem.

Fair warning to users of the new `gt` table building program.